# "www" as the owner of php file and nginx process, the script still cannot write?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, file-permissions

I am using a "duplicator" plugin on wordpress and required to configure the folder wp-snapshots, wp-snapshots/tmp to the owner of the php running process and I did.

Both folder and all files under are owned by "www". Nginx is run by "www". But I still can't pass the permission check.

I run "whoami" in a php scirpt to have confirmed the php script is running by www. So what's wrong?

Normally I just set the folder to 777 but I got fed up with this permission why thing. It happens all the time. What's wrong??

Thanks!

Comment: What are the current permissions on the `wp-snapshots` directory?

Comment: 755 on wp-snapshots folder, 644 on the files within it.

Comment: Well, really it's not that easy to help you but I'll give you a hint what I tend to do when I have similar issues. I just log myself in as the `www` user (by doing `su - www` with the root user and try to chase down the issue. You might need to change the `/etc/passwd` entry for the `www` user in order to be able to log in. Please share when you find the issue because now I'm curious :-) Good luck!

Comment: www has been configured as /sbin/nologin . Is this the reason? I can't login as "www" in this case. I think when I installed php-fpm, I created 'www' user as such.

Comment: No, it's not the reason. But if you change it to `/bin/bash` you'll be able to log in and then investigate.

Comment: Figured. The parent folder must also be owner by 'www' which were not..